# How to dispatch two RAC SignalProcedures one after another?

Tags: swift, multithreading, reactive-cocoa-4

I have a two `SignalProducers` making networks calls, one makes a regular server data request while the other checks if the current user token is still active and, in case it isn't, makes a refresh_token request.

The point is to make the token verification request (which **returns** a `SignalProducer<User, NetworkError>`) before calling the request data method (which returns a SignalProducer).

I have tried using a Scheduler, a Semaphore but I have trouble making any of these solutions work, I've also looked at the SignalProducer concat method but I'm at a loss about how it works, what is the best way to emulate this behavior?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the data types you're using and not sure if it's applicable so I hope it doesn't waste your time but could an NSOperation with dependency help you?

Comment: Can you try used flatmap?

Comment: Yes I did! I totally forgot to update this question but I resolved this using a flatMap with Merge strategy, which made the exact behavior I wanted. If somebody wants I can upload the answer here.